An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected
//@version=6
indicator("RSI Future test")

pine_rsi(float src, int len) => 
    change = ta.change(src)
    up = ta.rma(math.max(change, 0), len)
    down = ta.rma(-math.min(change, 0), len)
    down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

rsi_period = 14

rsi = pine_rsi(close, rsi_period)
plot(rsi, color=color.blue)

var rsiFuture = array.new_float(3) 

// calc future rsi - logic #1 (this is ok)
//array.set(rsiFuture, 0, pine_rsi(close, rsi_period-0))
//array.set(rsiFuture, 1, pine_rsi(close, rsi_period-1))
//array.set(rsiFuture, 2, pine_rsi(close, rsi_period-2))


//calc future rsi - logic #2 (this one occurs complile error)
for i=0 to 3    
    array.set(rsiFuture, i, pine_rsi(close, rsi_period-i))

This is a test code for description.
At the bottom, logic #1 works fine
The moment you move the same content to the for loop, you get the following compilation error.
> Error at 25:45 Cannot call 'pine_rsi' with argument 'len'='call 'operator -' (series int)'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.

Do you have any idea, Why does this happen?
So far, I've found that depending on the internal code content of the pine_rsi function, this error may or may not occur, but I don't know the exact solution.
